# How can I reduce the number of requests and use only one?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

My program does this:

1. Get the XML from my website
2. Run all the URLs
3. Get data from my web page (SKU, name, title, price, etc.) with requests
4. Get the lowest price from another website, by comparing the price with the same SKU with requests.

I'm using with lots of requests, on each def:

```
def get_Price (SKU):
    check ='https://www.XXX='+SKU
    r = requests.get(check)
    html = requests.get(r.url)
    bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.content,'html.parser')
    return Price

def get_StoreName (SKU):
    check ='https://XXX?keyword='+SKU
    r = requests.get(check)
    html = requests.get(r.url)
    bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.content,'html.parser')
    return storeName

def get_h1Tag (u):
    html = requests.get(u)
    bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.content,'xml')
    h1 = bsObj.find('h1',attrs={'itemprop':'name'}).get_text()
    return h1
```

How can I reduce the number of requests or connections to the URL - and use with one request or one connection throughout the whole program ?

Comment: Just to clarify, do you want to reduce the number of requests to a specific location (all get the same content) or to one server with different URLs? "to the URL" sounds like the former, "one connection throughout the program" like the latter

Comment: hi,  since im new at python - i've build def on each parameter i want - can i get all in one time ? it will reduce my process time ?

Comment: Is the URL in your multiple requests the same? If yes, the answer below works great, if not, it only adds additional stuff to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume this is a script with a group of methods you call in a particular order.
If so, this is a good use case for a `dict`. I would write a function that memorizes calls to URLs.

You can then reuse this function across your other functions:

```py
requests_cache = {}

def get_url (url, format_parser):
    if url not in requests_cache:
        r = requests.get(url)
        html = requests.get(r.url)
        requests_cache[url] = BeautifulSoup(html.content, format_parser)
    return requests_cache[url]

def get_Price (makat):
    url = 'https://www.zap.co.il/search.aspx?keyword='+makat
    bsObj = get_url(url, 'html.parser')
    # your code to find the price
    return zapPrice

def get_zapStoreName (makat):
    url = 'https://www.zap.co.il/search.aspx?keyword='+makat
    bsObj = get_url(url, 'html.parser')
    # your code to find the store name
    return storeName

def get_h1Tag (u):
    bsObj = get_url(u, 'xml')
    h1 = bsObj.find('h1',attrs={'itemprop':'name'}).get_text()
    return h1
```

If you want to avoid a global variable, you can also set `requests_cache` as attribute of `get_url` or as a default argument in the definition. The latter would also allow you to bypass the cache by passing an empty `dict`.

Again, the assumption here is that you are running this code as a script periodically. In that case, the `requests_cache` will get cleared every time you run the program.

However, if this is part of a larger program, you would want to 'expire' the cache on a regular basis, otherwise you would get the same results every time.

Comment: hi , thanks . yes - i'm running the script periodically . but im running it on all the url's in my sitemap . so the requests_cache is good here ? if i will use it - the cache wont be the data from the last request ?

Comment: Hi. The requests_cache should be good. The cache will contain response to the same request on the same url. Requests to different urls or with different params will not override each other. Every time your run the program, the requests_cache will be re-initialized. So, you will get fresh data every time you run the program

Comment: GREAT ! :) thanks . now i need to make the program run faster ...:)

Answer (score 0):

This is a good use case for the [requests-cache](https://requests-cache.readthedocs.io) library. Example:

```py
from requests_cache import CachedSession

# Save cached responses in a SQLite file (scraper_cache.sqlite), and expire after 6 minutes
session = CachedSession('scraper_cache.sqlite', expire_after=360)

def get_Price (SKU):
    check ='https://www.XXX='+SKU
    r = session.get(check)
    html = session.get(r.url)
    bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.content,'html.parser')
    return Price

def get_StoreName (SKU):
    check ='https://XXX?keyword='+SKU
    r = session.get(check)
    html = session.get(r.url)
    bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.content,'html.parser')
    return storeName

def get_h1Tag (u):
    html = session.get(u)
    bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.content,'xml')
    h1 = bsObj.find('h1',attrs={'itemprop':'name'}).get_text()
    return h1
```

Aside: with or without `requests-cache`, using sessions is good practice whenever you're making repeated calls to the same host, since it uses connection pooling: https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects